# Website Stuck on Load after few requests

Tags: craft3, php, error, apache

I'm facing a weird issue here.

I'm developing a CraftCMS based website and all seem to be working fine, until after a few requests (clicking around 4 ~ 5 requests) the website seem to keep loading and gets stuck, then browser returns an ERR_CONNECTION RESET error.

The weird thing is: Accessing any part of that domain on any browser within the network that I'm in gives seem to give an unresponsive (stuck loading forever). However accessing the domain from a different network seem to be working just fine. Restarting Apache server also does not seem to solve the issue.

I moved the site from one domain to another but the same problem persists.

Appreciate your help.

- CraftCMS v3.4 (devMode)
- PHP 7.4 (with all the recommended CraftCMS settings max_execution_time and memory)
- MySQL database

Comment: What happens if you turn dev mode off?

Comment: The same thing, no effect, also tried to change the environment to everything else "production", "staging", same effect.

Comment: Weird. Might be some overly strict ``mod_security`` settings in apache? Who's hosting?

Comment: It's a DigitalOcean VPS hosting, I don't think I have mod_security on I didn't see it loaded as part of Apache2 modules.